# can NSTreeController setcontent be used with NSXMLDocument?

Tags: nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller, nsxmldocument

I'm trying to display the content of a simple plist (xml) file in an outlineview.

Once I have the file data in either an NSXMLDocument or an NSDictionary, is it possible to just use this existing structure to populate the TreeController? All the code examples I can find parse through and reconstruct all the nodes and contents. Isn't this already established in the NSXMLDocument?

thanks

rob

Answer (score 4):

Bindings make this really easy.

You can use a NSTreeController combined with an NSOutlineView and very little code if you use standard bindings.

To make the NSXML objects in the sample application work together with the NSTreeController object, you simply have to add a couple methods to the NSXMLNode class through a category.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/UsingTreeControllers.html

```
#import "NSXMLNode+NSXMLNodeAdditions.h"

@implementation NSXMLNode (NSXMLNodeAdditions)

- (NSString *)displayName {
    NSString *displayName = [self name];
    if (!displayName) {
        displayName = [self stringValue];
    }
    return displayName;
}
- (BOOL)isLeaf {
    return [self kind] == NSXMLTextKind ? YES : NO;
}
@end
```

here are screenshots of the relevant settings for both the NSTreeContoller
[image]
[image]

and NSOutlineView's TableColumn
[image]